# Firebase authentication - users being created in console but progress bar won't stop spinning and the task is not completed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, mobile

So I am working on the registration form for a mobile-app and when a user fills out the registration form and submits, the progress bar appears and spins indefinitely and surprisingly no message is printed. In spite of this the users do appear in the firebase console causing me unthinkable bamboozlement.

Code:

```
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                User user = new User(fullName, rating, email);
    
                                System.out.println(user.fullName);
    
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                        .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User has been registered succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
System.out.println("Success!");
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }else {
                                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register! 
 Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
System.out.println("Failure!");
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages displayed?

Comment: None of the messages are displayed.

Comment: Is your second onComplete even triggered?

Comment: It can't be triggered or the else would fire off. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                            .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "User has been registered succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("Success!");
                                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            }else {
                                                Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register! 
     Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("Failure!");
                                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
 progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
    });
```

**Add this failure listener. So you can get failed message or do what you want.**

Comment: I added the listener and added a logcat inside the onFailure() method but still the message isn't printed and progress bar stays forever. I do see these errors/warnings though:                         Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.                                                       W/System: A resource failed to call close.